# Connect Wall - Grid Puzzles Edition!

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge, grid-deduction, connect-wall

<sub>*This is an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7045/60644).*</sub>

<sub>*Huge thanks to [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble) and [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) for playtesting! ><

And hey, this one may also mark my 100-day puzzle here in PSE, aye-aye the golden Socratic badge! XD*</sub>

---

[image]

> The $16$ grid puzzles above should be divided into $4$ categories of $4$, based on some shared properties.
> For the final answer, please find one or two grid puzzles that satisfy all $4$ categories!

Comment: Socratic badge incoming! Congratulations :)

Comment: (never mind my comment. I'm blind ;_;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The puzzle types are:

> Yajilin, Sashigane, Star battle, Kakuro
>  Tapa, Pencils, Numberlink, Tents
>  Hitori, ABC view, Slitherlink, Battleships
>  Aisuban, Masyu, Herugolf, Snake

The solved grids:

> [image]
>  (Note that the ABC view and the Kakuro have not been solved completely yet, since their solution is not unique)

The categories:

> Already solved puzzles: Numberlink, Battleships, Masyu, Herugolf
>  Puzzles with 2 solutions: Yajilin, Kakuro, ABC view, Aisuban
>  Puzzles on a 6 by 6 grid: Tapa, Pencils, Tents, Hitori
>  Puzzle types starting with S: Sashigane, Star battle, Slitherlink, Snake

My final answer:

> An underspecified 6 by 6 sudoku, which already has been solved! (the black digits are the original puzzle, the blue digits are filled in during the solving)
>  [image]

Comment: Nice going :) I was working towards a very similar conclusion but didn't know the second puzzle on the top row or the one bottom left - clearly two I now need to check out! One note: Your Tapa has a 2x2 square in it which means the solution needs a fix...!

Comment: @Stiv You are correct about the Tapa, fixed it now, thanks! I also didn't recognize all the puzzles immediately, I have searched through a couple of lists of puzzle types to get all the names (in particular I did not know the second puzzle from row 2 and also the bottom left puzzle).

Comment: Yup, the answer is correct, very well done! :D

Comment: However, your final answer should be updated by a bit as currently, it's having rot13(rvtug fbyhgvbaf) :)

Comment: @athin Whoops, I guess I wasn't paying enough attention when making that puzzle. It should be fixed now!

Comment: What are the rules for the second in row 2? Googling the name is not very helpful.

Comment: @Kruga see for example: https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/pencils.html